# UPSERT a row depending on the unique combination of values of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have the following table in a database:

```
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM (
    'void',
    'steady',
    'transition'
);

CREATE TABLE relations (
    marker integer NOT NULL,
    related integer[] NOT NULL,
    status status DEFAULT 'void'::status NOT NULL,
    id serial -- pgAdmin requires primary key
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY relations
    ADD CONSTRAINT pkey_id PRIMARY KEY (id);

INSERT INTO relations (marker, related, status)
VALUES
(3, '{6}', 'steady'::status),
(3, '{2}', 'transition'::status),
(6, '{4}', 'void'::status),
(6, '{2}', 'steady'::status),
(4, '{2}', 'steady'::status),
(4, '{6}', 'void'::status);
```

This is what the table looks like:

```
 marker | related |   status   | id 
--------+---------+------------+----
      3 | {6}     | steady     |  1
      3 | {2}     | transition |  2
      6 | {4}     | void       |  3
      6 | {2}     | steady     |  4
      4 | {2}     | steady     |  5
      4 | {6}     | void       |  6
```

The `marker/status` combinations are supposed to be unique, even though there is no corresponding constraint, yet. This is not the issue here.
I also have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_relations(integer, integer, status) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$
BEGIN
    update relations
        set related = array_append(related,
        (CASE
            WHEN marker = $1 THEN $2
            WHEN marker = $2 THEN $1
        END)
        )
    where
        marker in ($1,$2) AND
        status = $3;
END;
$_$;
```

When I run

```
SELECT update_relations(3, 4, 'void'::status);
```

then I want the row which `marker` value is `4` AND `status` is 'void' to update its `related` value and append a `3` to the array. Accordingly, the row that has `marker = 3` and `status = 'void'::status` shall append a `4` to its `related` array. However, this is the result:

```
 marker | related |   status   | id 
--------+---------+------------+----
      3 | {6}     | steady     |  1
      3 | {2}     | transition |  2
      6 | {4}     | void       |  3
      6 | {2}     | steady     |  4
      4 | {2}     | steady     |  5
      4 | {6,3}   | void       |  6
```

As you can see, the row with `marker = 4` and `status = 'void'::status` is updated as intended. Since there is no corresponding row that meets the requirement for 'marker = 3 and status = 'void'::status` no update happens. In such a case I would like to insert a row, so that the result would be:

```
 marker | related |   status   | id 
--------+---------+------------+----
      3 | {6}     | steady     |  1
      3 | {2}     | transition |  2
      6 | {4}     | void       |  3
      6 | {2}     | steady     |  4
      4 | {2}     | steady     |  5
      4 | {6,3}   | void       |  6
      3 | {4}     | void       |  7
```

How can I UPSERT the table, if a required `marker/status` combination is not present?

PS: I am using postgres 9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Postgres "upsert" function [ON CONFLICT UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) is for 9.5 and higher, but you're on 9.4.

If you're not worried about concurrency, you can do the simple:

```
if exists (select * from relations where marker in ($1,$2) AND status = $3) then
    update  relations
    set     ...
    where   marker in ($1,$2) AND status = $3;
else
    insert  into relations
            (marker, related, status)
    values  ($1, ARRAY[$2], $3);
end if
```

This approach does have concurrency issues.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql) for better (and more complex) solutions.